# ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave with img and overlay causing it to flicker

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave with img and overlay causing flickering.  This doesn't seem to happen when it's inside a div.  This seems to only happen on Chrome.

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/S44SgCsV4vTmVLnP?preview

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you show button, mouse leave event is triggered, because button is shown under mouse cursor. On mouse leave you hide button and mouse enter is triggered. This is the reason you are in endless loop looks like flickering. But this is expected behaviour and not a bug. Put mouse enter and mouse leave event one level higher.

Example:
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/tmgpXrnqqnQCr00f

Comment: Well the interesting part is that it only happens on img element and I have only seen this happen on Chrome not on Firefox.